# Python 3 Tkinter: ScrolledText does not recognize textvariable

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm creating a program which allows entrepreneurs to input details about their company (such as revenue, profit, debt), and the console analyzes those numbers and returns a grade with comments and a score out of 100.

I've made a ScrolledText widget on the right side of the program, below the "Total Points!" button.

Basically, every time the user clicks "Total Points!", it should display a score out of 100 and THEN display the grade and comments in the ScrolledText box.

But the problem is that it doesn't recognize the textvariable "FinalGrade" and the error shows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/s190528/PycharmProjects/CSP/Seeking Angel Investors GUI.py", line 433, in <module>
    txtFinalGrade = ScrolledText(f1,font=('arial',16,'bold'),textvariable=FinalGrade,bd=2,insertwidth=4, width=17, height=21,bg='steel blue', relief=FLAT).place(x=1280,y=180)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/tkinter/scrolledtext.py", line 26, in __init__
    Text.__init__(self, self.frame, **kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2947, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'text', cnf, kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2139, in __init__
    (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-textvariable"
```

Because the code is too long to paste here, I want to attach the link to it so you can copy and paste it into your python. Thanks.

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1WR5MO9GKDqSroIa0gCfnZpvpvIKPIEtzkHCQ5YzUaSI/edit

Comment: You're correct that `ScrolledText` does not take `textvariable`. You'll just have to use `get` method to retrieve the text and `insert` method to add text to it.

Comment: As per StackOverflow, [relevant code must be **in the body of the question itself**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). For one, if the link becomes unreachable, then the question becomes useless, and site quality suffers. Please also read **[MVE: Minimum Viable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** - you need to par down the code to include *only the parts necessary* to answer your specific question. Users should not need to troll through unnecessary code, or navigate elsewhere just to see the code. **Help us help you**. Entice volunteers to spend time on *your* question.

Answer (score 4):

`textvariable` doesn't work with `ScrolledText`, so you'll need to manually read/write to it:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText

root = tk.Tk()

# Make ScrolledText
txtFinalGrade = ScrolledText(root)
txtFinalGrade.pack()

# Add text to ScrolledText
txtFinalGrade.insert('1.0', 'hello world')

# Get text from ScrolledText
from_scrolledtext = txtFinalGrade.get('1.0', 'end')
print('Text inside ScrolledText is: ', from_scrolledtext)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I edited to show a full working example and fixed the issue. `txtFinalGrade` was being set as the output of call to `place(x=1280,y=180)`, which is `None` (and not output of `ScrolledText`).

Comment: @user8244818: ScrolledText class is derived from the Text class. So you get all the functionality of a tkinter Text widget, which happens to allow multiline text editing. You can make text editors with it. See http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm

Comment: I just edited my previous comment, but the problem is that you set `txtFinalGrade` as the output of `place` and not `ScrolledText`.

Comment: FWIW, `0.0` and `1.0` are incorrect text widget indexes. Indxes are strings, and the index of the first character is `”1.0”`.

Comment: @user8244818 Did you change your definition of `txtFinalGrade` (so the method `place` isn't called in the same line)? That's the most apparent reason for your error. And not to be rude but I'm not doing the work for you. Certainly willing to help if you put in honest effort.

Comment: Just follow the example I gave. Instead of using `pack`, replace it with your use of `place`. Of course you can throw in the specific parameters that you need. Something like: `txtFinalGrade = ScrolledText(...)` then `txtFinalGrade.place(...)`.

Answer (score 2):

ScrolledText is a Text widget not an Entry widget. Entry widgets are the ones with a variable binding as they only show strings so can be bound to a simple variable. A Text widget can contain text, images and other widgets along with formatting and so on and uses a tree data structure underneath.